# How to write test case for the given code using powermockito

Tags: junit4, powermock, testcase

I just want to know if i have a code like -

```
public class A {
    static String b = "hello";

public static String a() {
    String b = b();
    String d = d(b);
    String e = e(d, b);
    return e;
}

public static String b() {
    return b;
}

public static void c(String c) {
    b = c;
}

public static String d(String d) {
    return d;
}

public static String e(String e1, String e2) {

    return e1 + e2;
}
}
```

than how will i write the test cases for this using power mockito since all the methods are static and a method is even void too.

The first thing i got is that i only need to write the test case for method a since it is using all the other methods so all others will also get cover in it.
Can anybody help me and tell me how i can test this .

Comment: Strange ... why would you want to test methods with no external interface using mocks? Normally you only use mocks if you want to mask external behavior that is of no importance to the inner logic of your code. Your code example doesn't have any external interface, it has only inner logic. No need for mocks here, imho

Comment: actually this is just an example code .If i had a code like this which mask the  external behavior than how can i write the test case for the same

Comment: its just like i want to know how can i test the static and void static methods that are using another static mehod

Comment: You can't mock static methods with Mockito